# Scroll en FrameLayout (ActionBar)

Tags: java, android, xml

He desactivado la ActionBar desde la clase con:

> getSupportActionBar().hide();

Y en mi activity tengo este código:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#f4f4f4">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:background="#18a7af">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:id="@+id/logo_app"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

            <View
                android:background="#ffffffff"
                android:id="@+id/linea1"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_width="320dp" />

            <TextView
                android:text="Texto Prueba"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:textColor="#ffffffff"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="36sp" />

            <View
                android:background="#ffffffff"
                android:id="@+id/linea2"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_width="320dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </FrameLayout>
```

Cómo puedo hacer para que ese FrameLayout tenga un scroll como por ejemplo WhatsApp, dejo un ejemplo de lo que quiero hacer:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Te refieres a que esconde automáticamente el Toolbar cuando vas bajando de un scroll ?

Comment: Sí! Pero no del todo, solamente ocultar hasta el icono @FelixBeeb

Comment: mira este articulo, a ver si estamos hablando de lo mismo - http://www.sgoliver.net/blog/animaciones-basicas-coordinatorlayout/

Comment: Sí! Es eso lo que busco, pero que el scroll termine como el ejemplo que puse arriba, en la captura de la derecha, que no se oculte el "Texto Prueba" @FelixBeeb

Comment: no se si estará disponible esa función fuera de un toolbar ...

Comment: Bueno en toolbar también me serviría siempre y cuando pueda añadir el texto,  view e imagen, es posible? @FelixBeeb

Comment: mira este video y veras que si - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XMh3nbkd-hg al final del video hace la demostracion de lo que me refiero

Comment: Gracias @FelixBeeb ! Conseguí lo que quería hacer gracias a ese vídeo, solucionado.

Comment: Excelente, me alegra que te haya ayudado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente lo he conseguido solucionar con el comentario de @AshleyJosianne , el siguiente vídeo explica a la perfección lo que quería conseguir:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XMh3nbkd-hg

Gracias!